# ASP.NET WebApi testing - Asserting a request returns a 404 response

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have created an ApiController with the following method:

```
public User Get(int id)
{
    var user = DocumentSession.Load<User>(id);
    if(user!=null)
    {
        return Mapper.Map<User>(user); 
    }
    throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
}
```

I am trying to write a test for this method which asserts that when an invalid id is passed to the function, it returns an appropriate 404 response.

at the moment I have:

```
[Test]
public void get_invalid_user_returns_404()
{
    Assert.Throws<HttpResponseException>(()=>_usersController.Get(1001));
}
```

This works and passes, however it does not assert that it was a 404 response, simply that the right type of exception is thrown.  What should I be doing here to assert that the result was a 404?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that you are using NUnit, you can do this like this:

```
[Test]
public void get_invalid_user_returns_404()
{
    HttpResponseException ex = Assert.Throws<HttpResponseException>(()=>_usersController.Get(1001));
    Assert.That(ex.Response.StatusCode, Is.EqualTo(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
}
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Ha - That seems fairly obvious now.  Not sure I like the idea of the framework sending out the response due to a raised exception, so I'm going to change to explicitly return a response object. Thanks for your help.